# Solving equation $a_n=1+\frac12a_{n-1}+\frac12a_{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

Let's consider sequence following for $n=0...,T$ for which $a_0=a_T=0$. I want to solve equation $$a_n=1+\frac12a_{n+1}+\frac12a_{n-1}$$

**My work so far**

$$a_1=1+\frac12a_2 \Leftrightarrow a_2=2a_1-2$$
$$a_2=1+\frac12a_3+\frac12a_1 \Leftrightarrow2a_1-2=1+\frac12a_3 \Leftrightarrow a_3=3a_1-6$$
Also I calculated $a_4$ to get $a_4=4a_1-12$. So my observation is that for any $n \in \{1,...,T-1\}$
we have $$a_n=na_1+n(n-1)$$

And here I stacked, I'm not sure what to do next. Could you please give me a hand solving this equation ?

Comment: Just plugin  $n=T$ to solve for $a_1$ then you are done.

Comment: Did you get your guess by : $a_{n+1}-2a_n+a_{n-1}=-2\approx f''(x)\Rightarrow f(x)=-x^2+bx+c$ ? (The ballistic equation discretized). And then you plugged in the recurrence to check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_{n+1} - a_n -(a_n-a_{n-1}) = -2 \implies a_n - a_{n-1} = (a_1-a_0) - 2(n-1).$$

Can you take it from here?

> Next $$a_n-a_0=\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-a_{k-1}) = n(a_1-a_0) - 2\sum_{k=1}^n(k-1).$$

Lastly, plug in $n=T$ and solve for $a_1$.

Comment: Don't quite understand the very first equality. How did you derive it ?

Comment: I mean $ ...=-2$

Comment: Just re-arrange: $a_n=1+\frac12a_{n+1}+\frac12a_{n-1} \iff 2 a_n = 2+ a_{n+1} + a_{n-1} \iff -2 = a_{n+1} - 2a_n+a_{n-1} = (a_{n+1}-a_n) - (a_n-a_{n-1})$.

Comment: Okay I see, and how did you get corollary from that ? I mean $a_n-a_{n-1}=(a_1-a_0)-2(n-1)$. I see that it works but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: $b_n := a_n-a_{n-1}$ is an arithmetic sequence with step $-2$, so $b_n=b_1+(n-1)(-2)$.

Comment: Okay I see! And the hint in grey area has formally to be proved by induction or is there any simpler solution ?

Comment: No need for induction just sum over and derive directly. $2\sum_{k=1}^n (k-1)=n(n-1), a_0=0$, so $a_n=na_1-n(n-1).$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** Prove by induction that your guess is correct.

**Hint 2**  If $a_T=0$ then
$$Ta_1+T(T-1)=0$$

Use this to find $a_1$.

Comment: Could you please show me how it can be proven using induction ?

Comment: You prove $P(1)$ and $P(2)$ and then you use the recurssion to prove the inductive step @Lucian

Answer (score 1):

Consider the generating function $$f(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^n,\qquad|x|<1.$$
We may write
$$2a_{n+1}x^{n+2}=2x^{n+2}+a_{n+2}x^{n+2}+a_{n}x^{n+2},$$
and sum over $n\ge 0$:
$$2x\sum_{n\ge0}a_{n+1}x^{n+1}=2x^2\sum_{n\ge0}x^n+\sum_{n\ge0}a_{n+2}x^{n+2}+x^2\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^n,$$
which is
$$2x(f(x)-a_0)=\frac{2x^2}{1-x}+f(x)-a_0-a_1x+x^2f(x).$$
Using $a_0=0$, and treating $a_1$ as a constant,
$$(x^2-2x+1)f(x)=\frac{(a_1+2)x^2-a_1x}{x-1},$$
so that
$$f(x)=\frac{(a_1+2)x^2-a_1x}{(x-1)^3}.$$
Then let the sequences $p_n$ and $q_n$ be defined by
$$\begin{align}
p(x)=\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^3}&=\sum_{n\ge0}p_nx^n\\
q(x)=\frac{x}{(x-1)^3}&=\sum_{n\ge0}q_nx^n,
\end{align}$$
so that
$$f(x)=(a_1+2)p(x)-a_1q(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}((a_1+2)p_n-a_1q_n)x^n,$$
giving $a_n=(a_1+2)p_n-a_1q_n$.
Differentiating the series $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n\ge0}x^n$ three times gives
$$\frac{1}{(x-1)^3}=\sum_{n\ge0}x^n\left(-\frac{1}{2}(n+1)(n+2)\right),$$
so that
$$\begin{align}
p(x)=\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^3}&=\sum_{n\ge0}x^n\left(-\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)\right)\quad &\Rightarrow p_n=-\frac12n(n-1)\\
q(x)=\frac{x}{(x-1)^3}&=\sum_{n\ge0}x^n\left(-\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)\right)\quad &\Rightarrow q_n=-\frac12n(n+1).
\end{align}$$
Therefore
$$a_n=(a_1+2)p_n-a_1q_n=n(a_1+1-n).$$
To find $a_1$, we use $a_T=0$. Specifically we have
$$T(a_1+1-T)=0\Rightarrow a_1=T-1.$$

> Thus we have $$a_n=n(T-n).$$